# Area chart,scrollable, with selectors and range filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I want to implement a chart with jquery with the features as in [yahoo finance](https://in.finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=AAPL#symbol=AAPL;range=1d) . Please help me in finding a good plugin without any performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

use this one it good performed charts
it has mobile support and it is well known chart plugin
it uses jquery

http://chartjs.devexpress.com/Demo

---

**Enjoy :)**